# Can I call a Microsoft BotBuilder like calling a function?

Tags: botframework

I am trying to build a bot and use it within a chat app. I think Microsoft Bot Builder is the one for me.

I looked into its documentations and tried them in the emulator. 
I noticed that in these examples, you send texts to the bot either using 
"consoleconnector" or "chatconnector", as the example shows.

```
 server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

 // Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message 
 back (prefixed with 'You said:')
 var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
  });
```

I don't want a new endpoint. I want to call the bot like calling a function: give the incoming message from a user and the function returns bot's response.

Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how to do it.

If it is not possible, then only way is to call it as a rest API as shown above.
In this case, do i still need "MICROSOFT_APP_ID" and "MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD"? 
Note that, I don't want to deploy the bot to azure or aws now. I want to use it local.

Could anyone help me explain these? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bot Framework is built to function as an API - it takes a request and sends a response. The framework doesn't provide a callback or promise to capture the response so this approach simply wouldn't work. Take a look at the [DirectLine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts) if you want to embed the framework within another application.

You need to use the MS App id and password for all channels apart from the [Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator). If you use DirectLine API, you will also have to pass a secret token.